# Passing authentication data to another website

Tags: security, authentication

There are two applications AppA and AppB. User is authenticated in AppA. When users clicks a link in AppA I want to redirect him to AppB and pass authentication data to AppB, so user can be automatically authenticated in AppB under the same credentials. 
Is there a common approach of passing authentication data from one website to another? 
How can I do it in the most secure way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the username and password encrypted over a query string or a shared cookie.

If you have the private_key shared on AppB you can decrypt anything you encrypt on AppA.

Run this to generate your public and private key.

```
openssl genrsa -out public_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in public_key.pem -pubout > private_key.pub
```

Here you can encrypt\decrypt using your new key.

```
function encrypt($data)
{
    if (openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, file_get_contents("/home/blah/key/private_key.pem")))
        $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
    else
        throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

    return $data;
}
function decrypt($data)
{
    if (openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $decrypted, file_get_contents("/home/blah/key/private_key.pem")))
        $data = $decrypted;
    else
        $data = '';

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Passing sensitive data in the querystring is a no-no. Also, how would you have the user's password to send to the other site? It should be salted+hashed in the database.